# Pine Script (TradingView) - How to move a Stop Loss to the Take Profit level

Tags: pine-script

There is a Pine Script code on TradingView where we have 2 Take Profit levels and 2 Stop Loss levels: [tradingview.com](https://www.tradingview.com/script/tGTV8MkY-Two-Take-Profits-and-Two-Stop-Loss/).
When the first take profit is achieved, half of the position is closed and the first stop loss is moved to the entry level (break-even).

Do you have any ideas how to make 3 Take Profit levels with following logic:

- When TP 1 is reached, SL is moved to break-even
- When TP 2 is reached, SL is moved to TP 2
- When TP 3 is reached, exit the position

Tkanks a lot for helping!

```
//@version=4
strategy("SL1 Pips after TP1 (MA)", commission_type=strategy.commission.cash_per_order, overlay=true, default_qty_value=1000, initial_capital=100)

// Strategy
Buy  = input(true)
Sell = input(true)

// Date Range
start_year    = input(title='Start year'   ,defval=2020)
start_month   = input(title='Start month'  ,defval=1)
start_day     = input(title='Start day'    ,defval=1)
start_hour    = input(title='Start hour'   ,defval=0)
start_minute  = input(title='Start minute' ,defval=0)
end_time      = input(title='set end time?',defval=false)
end_year      = input(title='end year'     ,defval=2019)
end_month     = input(title='end month'    ,defval=12)
end_day       = input(title='end day'      ,defval=31)
end_hour      = input(title='end hour'     ,defval=23)
end_minute    = input(title='end minute'   ,defval=59)

// MA
ema_period = input(title='EMA period',defval=10)
wma_period = input(title='WMA period',defval=20)
ema        = ema(close,ema_period)
wma        = wma(close,wma_period)

// Entry Condition
buy =
 crossover(ema,wma) and
 nz(strategy.position_size) == 0 and Buy and
 time > timestamp(start_year, start_month, start_day, start_hour, start_minute) and
 (end_time?(time < timestamp(end_year, end_month, end_day, end_hour, end_minute)):true)
 
sell =
 crossunder(ema,wma) and
 nz(strategy.position_size) == 0 and Sell and
 time > timestamp(start_year, start_month, start_day, start_hour, start_minute) and
 (end_time?(time < timestamp(end_year, end_month, end_day, end_hour, end_minute)):true)

// Pips
pip = input(20)*10*syminfo.mintick

// Trading parameters //
var bool  LS  = na
var bool  SS  = na
var float EP  = na
var float TVL = na
var float TVS = na
var float TSL = na
var float TSS = na
var float TP1 = na
var float TP2 = na
var float SL1 = na
var float SL2 = na

if buy or sell and strategy.position_size == 0
    EP  := close
    SL1 := EP - pip     * (sell?-1:1)
    SL2 := EP - pip     * (sell?-1:1)
    TP1 := EP + pip     * (sell?-1:1)
    TP2 := EP + pip * 2 * (sell?-1:1) 
   
// current trade direction    
LS := buy  or strategy.position_size > 0
SS := sell or strategy.position_size < 0

// adjust trade parameters and trailing stop calculations
TVL := max(TP1,open) - pip[1]
TVS := min(TP1,open) + pip[1]
TSL := open[1] > TSL[1] ? max(TVL,TSL[1]):TVL 
TSS := open[1] < TSS[1] ? min(TVS,TSS[1]):TVS

if LS and high > TP1
    if open <= TP1
        SL2:=min(EP,TSL)
    
if SS and low < TP1
    if open >= TP1
        SL2:=max(EP,TSS)

// Closing conditions
close_long  = LS and open < SL2
close_short = SS and open > SL2

// Buy
strategy.entry("buy"  , strategy.long, when=buy and not SS)
strategy.exit ("exit1", from_entry="buy", stop=SL1, limit=TP1, qty_percent=50)
strategy.exit ("exit2", from_entry="buy", stop=SL2, limit=TP2)

// Sell
strategy.entry("sell" , strategy.short, when=sell and not LS)
strategy.exit ("exit3", from_entry="sell", stop=SL1, limit=TP1, qty_percent=50)
strategy.exit ("exit4", from_entry="sell", stop=SL2, limit=TP2)

// Plots
a=plot(strategy.position_size >  0 ? SL1 : na, color=#dc143c, style=plot.style_linebr)
b=plot(strategy.position_size <  0 ? SL1 : na, color=#dc143c, style=plot.style_linebr) 
c=plot(strategy.position_size >  0 ? TP1 : na, color=#00ced1, style=plot.style_linebr) 
d=plot(strategy.position_size <  0 ? TP1 : na, color=#00ced1, style=plot.style_linebr) 
e=plot(strategy.position_size >  0 ? TP2 : na, color=#00ced1, style=plot.style_linebr) 
f=plot(strategy.position_size <  0 ? TP2 : na, color=#00ced1, style=plot.style_linebr) 
g=plot(strategy.position_size >= 0 ? na  : EP, color=#ffffff, style=plot.style_linebr) 
h=plot(strategy.position_size <= 0 ? na  : EP, color=#ffffff, style=plot.style_linebr) 

plot(ema,title="ema",color=#fff176)
plot(wma,title="wma",color=#00ced1)
```

Tkanks a lot for helping!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the example what you need:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © adolgov

// @description
// when tp1 is reached, sl is moved to break-even
// when tp2 is reached, sl is moved to tp1
// when tp3 is reached - exit

//@version=4
strategy("Stepped trailing strategy example", overlay=true)

// random entry condition
longCondition = crossover(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

// sl & tp in points
sl = input(100)
tp1 = input(100)
tp2 = input(200)
tp3 = input(300)

curProfitInPts() =>
    if strategy.position_size > 0
        (high - strategy.position_avg_price) / syminfo.mintick
    else if strategy.position_size < 0
        (strategy.position_avg_price - low) / syminfo.mintick
    else
        0
        
calcStopLossPrice(OffsetPts) =>
    if strategy.position_size > 0
        strategy.position_avg_price - OffsetPts * syminfo.mintick
    else if strategy.position_size < 0
        strategy.position_avg_price + OffsetPts * syminfo.mintick
    else
        0
        
calcProfitTrgtPrice(OffsetPts) =>
    calcStopLossPrice(-OffsetPts)

getCurrentStage() =>
    var stage = 0
    if strategy.position_size == 0 
        stage := 0
    if stage == 0 and strategy.position_size != 0
        stage := 1
    else if stage == 1 and curProfitInPts() >= tp1
        stage := 2
    else if stage == 2 and curProfitInPts() >= tp2
        stage := 3
    stage

stopLevel = -1.
profitLevel = calcProfitTrgtPrice(tp3)

// based on current stage set up exit
// note: we use same exit ids ("x") consciously, for MODIFY the exit's parameters
curStage = getCurrentStage()
if curStage == 1
    stopLevel := calcStopLossPrice(sl)
    strategy.exit("x", loss = sl, profit = tp3, comment = "sl or tp3")
else if curStage == 2
    stopLevel := calcStopLossPrice(0)
    strategy.exit("x", stop = stopLevel, profit = tp3, comment = "breakeven or tp3")
else if curStage == 3
    stopLevel := calcStopLossPrice(-tp1)
    strategy.exit("x", stop = stopLevel, profit = tp3, comment = "tp1 or tp3")
else
    strategy.cancel("x")
```

How it works you can see [here](https://www.tradingview.com/script/jjhUHcje-Stepped-trailing-strategy-example/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is literally thing I have tried to do for the last 3 months

Comment: Hi Andrey, 

Could you make little edit to the script? When stoploss is calculated and if commission fee is used it would be nice to have commission fee calculated to SL, so when breakeven happens it would actually be breakeven and not slightly less.

Of course I can change the code :
calcStopLossPrice(OffsetPts) =>
    if strategy.position_size > 0
        strategy.position_avg_price - OffsetPts * syminfo.mintick

to something like this:
calcStopLossPrice(OffsetPts) =>
    if strategy.position_size > 0
        (strategy.position_avg_price - OffsetPts * syminfo.mintick) * 1.001

Comment: There are no way to get commission setting in the Pine code in TV now (. The workaround could be in hardcode commission calculation formula in the strategy and using this formula for calculate SL level

Comment: Hi Andrey! Can this be modified to use % based TP and SL?

Comment: Yes. Here https://www.tradingview.com/script/kHhCik9f-Multiple-profit-exits-example/ there are the helper function for convert %% to points/ticks. You can use this function here.